# select multiple value using python and xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I can without problem select single value using xpath in python but how to join few single xpath to get one?
here is sample fragment of html source (`r.content`):

```
<div class="members">
    <h2>Members</h2>
    <div class="member">
        <span title="Last Online:&nbsp;2017-02-20 22:37:42" data-time="2017-02-20T22:37:42Z">
          <span class="profile-link">
            <a href="/account/view-profile/KonterBolet">
              <img class="achievement" src="36.png" alt="Completed 36" title="Completed 36">KonterA</a>
          </span>
          <span class="memberType">Leader</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="member">
        <span title="Last Online:&nbsp;2017-02-19 11:28:20" data-time="2017-02-19T11:28:20Z">
          <span class="profile-link hasTwitch twitchOffline" data-twitch-user="mardok_tv">
            <a href="/account/view-profile/mardok">
              <img class="achievement" src="35.png" alt="Completed 35" title="Completed 35">mardok</a>
            <a class="twitch" href="//www.twitch.tv/mardok_tv" target="_blank" title="Offline"></a>
          </span>
          <span class="memberType">Officer</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use python `requests` to get content and `lxml` to parse it

```
import requests
from lxml import html
ses = requests.session()
r = ses.get(SITE_URL)
webContent = html.fromstring(r.content)
```

first xpath:
`acc = webContent.xpath("//span/a[contains(@href,'account/view-profile')]/text()")`
and result:
`['konterA', 'mardok']`

second xpath :
`twitch = webContent.xpath('//span/@data-twith-user')`
and result:
`['mardok_tv']`

third xpath:
`lastOnline = webContent.xpath('//span/@data-time')`
and result:
`['2017-02-20T22:37:42Z','2017-02-19T11:28:20Z']`

**How to join this three together to get result like this:**
`[['konterA','','2017-02-20T22:37:42Z'],['mardok','mardok_tv','2017-02-19T11:28:20Z']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider parsing all items together under same parent, iterating on a top-level `xpath`. And use XPath's `concat()` to return an empty length string `''` if no attrib/element value exists. Below also uses XPath's `normalize-space()` to remove line breaks and carriage returns from values.

```
# PARSING POSTED SNIPPET AS STRING
webContent = html.fromstring(htmlstr)

# INITIALIZING LISTS
acc = []; twitch = []; lastOnline = []

# ITERATING THROUGH SECOND CHILD <SPAN>
for i in webContent.xpath("//span/span[1]"):    
    acc.append(i.xpath("concat(normalize-space(a[contains(@href,'account/view-profile')]),'')"))
    twitch.append(i.xpath("concat(@data-twitch-user, '')"))
    lastOnline.append(i.xpath("concat(../@data-time, '')"))

# ZIP EQUAL LENGTH LISTS
xpath_list = list(zip(acc, twitch, lastOnline))

print(xpath_list)
# [('KonterA', '', '2017-02-20T22:37:42Z'), ('mardok', 'mardok_tv', '2017-02-19T11:28:20Z')]
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, this is exactly what I need, I try get it in many ways but I never ever consider iterfind. Thanks!

Comment: You actually don't need `iterfind()` as `xpath()` will do. See update! One of those "of course..." moments. Iterfind comes from the built-in `etree` but traverses elements like lxml's xpath.

Answer (score 0):

let's call them `first_list, second_list and third_list`.
Modify `second_list` as:

```
second_list = [ i if i.strip("_tv") in first_list else "" for i in second_list ]
```

after that, do :

```
 zip(first_list, second_list, third_list)
```

This should give you a list of tuples in same way.

```
[('konterA','','2017-02-20T22:37:42Z'),('mardok','mardok_tv','2017-02-19T11:28:20Z')]
```

Comment: I can't simply join lists together because values on this list are totaly different not only '_tv' part

Comment: @mastaBot, then how do you know where to put the word ? For eg. if there was "foo" in place of "mardok_tv", then what should be the output ?

Comment: I don't know and then I need to do it like in @Parfait example.